# Convert an ff object to a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, bigdata, ff

I am working with big matrix and the ff package.
I am loading an ff object and I want to use it to calculate a crps (a score).

For example, I have a ff_matrix (called Mat with 25 rows and 7303 columns) which is a precipitation forecast (7303 represents the number of days (about 20 years) and 25 are the 25 precipitation simulations for one day). I also have a ff_array with the observations for these 20 years (called Obs and with 7303 values).

With the package ensembleBMA I want to calculate  the CRPS. I need to put my ff_matrix and my ff_array in an "ensembleBMA" object (in fact this is a data.frame).

For this code:

```
ensembleBMA(Mat,Obs)
```

I have this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class 'c("ff_matrix", "ff_array", "ff")' into a data.frame
```

I tried different options such as:

```
as.data.frame(Mat)
as.matrix(Mat)
transform.ffdf(as.ffdf(Mat))
```

I always have these errors:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(Mat_Ptot_212_1) : cannot automatically convert class  'c("ff_matrix", "ff_array", "ff")' into a data frame (data.frame)
```

or

```
opening ff /tmp/RtmpWrlY4n/clone9d3376b435.ff Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered,  : write error
```

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Since when is 25*7303 considered big?

Comment: Since I have 200 000 matrix like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way us to first convert your `ff_array` to an array and convert that to a `data.frame`:

```
Mat <- ff(1, vmode="double", dim=c(25, 7303))
as.data.frame(Mat[,])
```

or first convert your `ff_array` to an `ffdf` and convert that to an `data.frame`:

```
 as.ffdf(Mat)[,]
```

or

```
as.data.frame(as.ffdf(Mat))
```

The last two solutions seem to be much slower than the first. This has probably to do with the large number of columns which slows down `as.ffdf` which has to create 7303 files.

There does not seem to be a `as.data.frame.ff_array`.